# Excel Group Large Data Set Automatically

Tags: excel

I have a large data set that is in this form, however it is several thousand parts long.

[image]

(Note corporate QTY's are not always the sum of all the stores, as sometimes there is some corporate stock separately).

As of now they are all in that form, with the corporate row at the top of every group.  I would like to do the equivalent of

1)Selecting all the rows inbetween two corporate entries
2)Grouping them

The result would be:

[image]

However is there a way to do this automatically so I don't have to select the rows in a group manually and hit the group button several thousand times?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337267/grouping-rows-in-vba

Comment: or you can use PivotTable https://www.google.com/search?q=pivot+table+group+tabular&tbm=vid

Comment: There is a lot of other data after C that we would like to be able to see if desired, however not always necessary.  So we would really like to group, not pivot.

I'm not familiar with vba at all, how much work would have to be done to that code to make it work on mine