# Grouping according to parent child relationship by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose my project has n number of items and each item as one parent assign to them. I want to group the same according to parent child relationship.
[In the 1st screenshoot the row number 769 has child from 770 to 896](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA1j9.png). So i want my result as Screenshot 2 which group row from 770 to 896 under 769 [Sample result require](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1okdm.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Read [ask] and then tell us what you want to do and show your [mcve] and show your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to a new module ...

```
Public Sub PerformOutlineOnSelectedRows()
    Dim i As Long, lngLevel As Long

    Selection.Rows.ClearOutline

    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        lngLevel = UBound(Split(Selection.Cells(i, 1), ".")) + 1

        If lngLevel > 8 Then lngLevel = 8

        Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.OutlineLevel = lngLevel
    Next
End Sub
```

... then select the rows you want to group and outline and then run the macro from the **Developer** tab in the ribbon.

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind, the group and outline functionality only goes to 8 levels so anything below that won't group properly.

Let me know if it works or if you need more info.

Comment: What if i want to go above 8 Level.

Comment: @AnkitSingh unfortunately you can’t, it’s a limitation in Excel. If my code doesn’t check for levels below 8, it will cause a run time error. How many levels do you go to?

Comment: no issue my problem is solved. Thanks for your help and support

Comment: @AnkitSingh no worries. Always happy to help.